# java erro em conexão com SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Estou tentando conectar em um banco de dados sql server, porém não estou obtendo êxito.
Segue classe de conexão e método de teste:

```
public class ConexaoBanco {

    public static final String user = "sa";
    public static final String pswd = "**********"; 

    public static Connection conexao() {

        Connection con = null;
        final String jdbcDriver="com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver";
        final String caminho= "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=cliente";

        try {

            Class.forName(jdbcDriver);          
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(caminho, user, pswd);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());         
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println();           
        }       
        return con;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Connection conex = ConexaoBanco.conexao();
            if (conex != null ) {
                System.out.println("conectado");
            } else {
                System.out.println("não conectado");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: Poste o erro que você esta tendo.

Comment: Não gera erro. Quando executo, ele exibe "não conectado", mensagem essa programada no teste do retorno do método de conexão.

Comment: Tira a condição de dentro do `try` pra ver a mensagem de erro retornada no teu `catch`

Comment: Não entendi bem. Devo tirar apenas a instanciação do objeto de dentro do try, ou o if/else também?

Comment: `try {
            Connection conex = ConexaoBanco.conexao();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } `

Comment: Não retorna nada, console fica em branco.

Answer (score 0):

eu tenho este exemplo aqui que uso por padrão em minhas aplicações de java:

```
final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    plogin = new JPanel();

    lnick = new JLabel("Nick: ");
    tnick = new JTextField(30);
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("TESTE BANCO DE DADOS");
    JLabel lsenha = new JLabel("Senha: ");
    senha = new JPasswordField(30);
    blogin = new JButton("Login");
    JButton bcadastrar = new JButton("Cadastrar");
    l1.setBounds(135, 100, 450, 50);
    blogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {
                Class.forName(driver);
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:Mysql://127.0.0.1/testinsert", "root", "root");
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

                String senha1 = String.valueOf(senha.getPassword());  // converter para string ja que o pw retorna char

                String sql = "SELECT nick FROM testinsert.cadastro where nick='" + tnick.getText() + "' and '" + senha1 + "';";

                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tnick.getText());
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, senha1);

                System.out.println(tnick.getText());
                System.out.println(senha1);

                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);                          

                rs.next();


                //String nick = rs.getString("nick");

                if (tnick.getText() != null && senha.getPassword() != null) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuário Ativo");
                    plogin.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    menu();
                }

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Impossivel carregar o driver");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuário ou Senha Inválidos");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Este seria um código de login padrão, do qual quando vou fazer o cadastro só altero a linha em que é feito um SELECT, coloco INSERT, é bom você ver se realmente seu plugin do java, que conecta ao banco está funcionando, as vezes é bom criar um projeto novo e linkar novamente o conector **(.jar)** que você está utilizando!